# Subroutines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In VBA you can define a reusable block code by creating a Sub and calling it in code. I understand you can't do this in JavaScript with the same technique, but obviously there must be a  way to do this. I understand you can use functions, but I honestly can't make heads or tails of it. I want to call the following code multiple times in my program, how can this be achieved in JavaScript?

```
$("select[title='Mon']").prop("disabled", true);
$("input[title='M1Sent']").prop("disabled", true);
$("input[title='HotelCheckIn']").prop("disabled", true);
$("input[title='HotelCheckOut']").prop("disabled", true);
$("textarea[title='Diet']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a single javascript file? Please be aware that in javascript you don't have namespaces, usings, etc.

Comment: Functions are what you want

Comment: Wrap your code in a function: `function myFunc(){ /*code*/ }`, and call it as: `myFunc();`

Comment: Take a look at documentation [JavaScript#Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions#t=201703171613250056266)

Comment: @Shilly, Sorry mate, just flying by the seat of my pants here and asking for help. I didn't realize you had to be a certain skill level to ask a question on here. I love this site, a lot of kind folks with a lot of knowledge to share. Thanks to everybody else who took the time to share a productive comment... unlike Silly.. whoops freudian slip, my apologies

Comment: Kudos to @Washington Guedes, much appreciated the reference and the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create a function:

```
function myFunction() {
    //what you want executed goes here
}
```

Then you put what you want done in that function:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("select[title='Mon']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='M1Sent']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='HotelCheckIn']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='HotelCheckOut']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("textarea[title='Diet']").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

And to call it, you just type `myFunction();`, which you can do however many times you wish.

Alternatively, if you want it to repeat over and over, you could pop `myFunction` into `setInterval(myFunction, milliseconds)` or bind it to some event in an html element, for example `<input type="submit" onsubmit="myFunction();"> ... </input>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a shot, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First define the function:

```
function doThings() {
    $("select[title='Mon']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='M1Sent']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='HotelCheckIn']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("input[title='HotelCheckOut']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("textarea[title='Diet']").prop("disabled", true); 
}
```

You can now call this function repeatedly like this:

```
doThings();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Put your snippet in a separate javascript file if you want 
**2-** make sure to load it before any other sub code you want to use it in.
**3-** jquery is a dependency here so your script needs to be included after jquery

```
var usable = function() {
        var myFunction = function() {
            $("select[title='Mon']").prop("disabled", true);
            $("input[title='M1Sent']").prop("disabled", true);
            $("input[title='HotelCheckIn']").prop("disabled", true);
            $("input[title='HotelCheckOut']").prop("disabled", true);
            $("textarea[title='Diet']").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        return {
            myFunction: myFunction
        };
    }();
```

you can add any re-usable function and then call it like this:

```
usable.myFunction()
```

and just include it like a normal javascript file in your html.

Comment: Technically a solid solution, but you might want to introduce the function paradigma and the module pattern in separate steps, as OP might not be familiar with both.